# Iterate over a list of dictionary with a list of dictionary inside

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

I am playing around with a simple blockchain. I wanna get the total number of transacted amounts in my code, but this Method only returns one value! which is the default value. Here is my sample chain.

```
"chain": [
        {
            "index": 1,
            "previous_hash": "1",
            "proof": 0,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:46:27.100441",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "reciver": "-",
                    "sender": "-"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "previous_hash": "e267a3f77fe50af86466a9bc5fce5b8285cf3eff85260f402074505c6023a085",
            "proof": 115558,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:48:29.790718",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 420.69,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1142,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "yaser"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 100,
                    "reciver": "Miner",
                    "sender": "01656f68288a45f993fc8c35c3d853d1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "previous_hash": "217a9bb5994943e03cef59edac125cc33c1831dce9d3ce8424ca134068e808b5",
            "proof": 48245,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:49:18.885861",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 462,
                    "reciver": "Yaser",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 32,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 100,
                    "reciver": "Miner",
                    "sender": "01656f68288a45f993fc8c35c3d853d1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and this is my code:

I tried to go through each layer and do a for loop, meanwhile I do not know if my syntax is wrong or correct.

```
def total_trans(self):
    balance=0
    for i in self.chain:
        for key , value in self.chain[0].items() :
            for x in self.chain[0]['transactions']:
                for k , v in self.chain[0]['transactions'][0].items():
                    balance += sum(self.chain[0]['transactions'][0]['amount'] for i in self.chain[0]['transactions'][0])

    return balance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you keep referring to the first item in the chain instead of letting the for loops iterate over the data.

Try this:

```py
    def total_trans(self):
        balance = 0.0
        for i in self.chain:
            for x in i['transactions']:
                balance += x['amount']    
        return balance
```

With your data, I get `balance` returned as `2256.69`

In general, when you have a deeply nested data structure like this, you should write your program so it has just the outer most loop first: `for i in self.chain:` in your case. Then you can just add `print(i)` to see what you have. Then you would realise that you are after the `transactions` and then you just keep going, iterating over something else, and printing, until you get what you want.

Comment: works like a clock, thanks for the hint ... I needed this <3

Answer (score 2):

I made the original chain a python dictionary. If you are importing this JSON object from an external file you can use the [JSON built in libray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to deserialise it to a Python object.

```
block_chain = {"chain": [
        {
            "index": 1,
            "previous_hash": "1",
            "proof": 0,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:46:27.100441",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "reciver": "-",
                    "sender": "-"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "previous_hash": "e267a3f77fe50af86466a9bc5fce5b8285cf3eff85260f402074505c6023a085",
            "proof": 115558,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:48:29.790718",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 420.69,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 1142,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "yaser"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 100,
                    "reciver": "Miner",
                    "sender": "01656f68288a45f993fc8c35c3d853d1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "previous_hash": "217a9bb5994943e03cef59edac125cc33c1831dce9d3ce8424ca134068e808b5",
            "proof": 48245,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-13 12:49:18.885861",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": 462,
                    "reciver": "Yaser",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 32,
                    "reciver": "John",
                    "sender": "Hoomehr"
                },
                {
                    "amount": 100,
                    "reciver": "Miner",
                    "sender": "01656f68288a45f993fc8c35c3d853d1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the nested loop extracts each "amount" and adds it to the balance variable, which is returned:

```py
def total_trans(block_chain):
    balance = 0
    chain = block_chain["chain"]  # get chain (list of blocks)
    for block in chain:  # each element in array (block, type dict)
        for trans in block["transactions"]:  # get transactions key
            balance += trans["amount"]  # add each amaout for each transaction to the balance
    return balance

print(total_trans(block_chain))  # returns : 2256.69
```

Within your class it would look like:

```py
def total_trans(self):
    balance = 0
    chain = self.block_chain["chain"]  # get chain (list of blocks)
    for block in chain:  # each element in array (block, type dict)
        for trans in block["transactions"]:  # get transactions key
            balance += trans["amount"]  # add each amaout for each transaction to the balance
    return balance
```

Comment: Amazing , Thanks